# Is statistical power relevant if there is no focus on significance/hypothesis testing?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, effect-size, statistical-power

If there is no focus on NHST and P-values, then are power analyses even necessary? What if someone were to focus solely on effect sizes and confidence intervals (I know that p-values and CIs share similar statistical theories) so if someone could explain this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about whether there's a good chance your confidence interval would include the value (or set of values) that would be under the "null" in some corresponding hypothesis test (indicating the possibility of no difference/no effect) then considering power would be important.

If you really don't care about that, then things may be different.

You don't give enough information to tell much about what the situation is, though, so it's hard to say much more (I can't guess whether you're in a situation where you'd care; many people would, but some might not).

One way to think about using power studies to identify sample size is it gives a way to identify a sample large enough to have a good chance to say that a *meaningful* difference (in some sense relevant to whatever you're looking at) is not simply explainable by the action of random noise in your results.  (We see a big difference and it can't easily be dismissed as a chance effect.)

Comment: I would rather argue like this for the confidence intervals: confidence intervals are often derived from inverted hypothesis tests.  The higher the power of this hypothesis test, the narrower the confidence interval will be for such intervals. So inverting a test with higher power will result in 'more precise' (narrower) confidence intervals.

Comment: Sure, but the issues are still basically the same ... if you don't care whether or not your intervals are likely to include some null value, maybe you don't need them to be narrow.

Comment: Well that I see, but what then is a 'confidence interval' ?  I would day that it is an interval in which we believe with some degree of confidence that the true value lies in ? So if you don't care about whether or not your intervals contain a true value then are you still talking about a confidence interval ?

Comment: No, you misunderstand; the null value is not the true value. The CI will still have at least the required coverage.

Answer (score 0):

As @Glen_b pointed out, it depends on the nature of your problem. However that said, I often find that it's still useful to keep track of the p-value as a way to easily detect and discard seemingly-large effect sizes which aren't likely to replicate. You can do this with confidence intervals too of course, but that requires asking a more complicated question ("does the baseline value fall inside this region") vs a simple "is p < cutoff".

If you're just running a single test, then this doesn't really matter, but on those occasions where I've cared primarily about effect size as opposed to significance, it's generally because I'm running a very large number of tests, and want to reduce each one down to a single number. However even keeping confidence intervals on hand in this case, you would be misled due to the problem of [multiple testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem), and would be unable to correct for it without knowing the p-values.

So in short, yes, it does still help to keep p-values handy.

Comment: Isn't Holm-Bonferroni too conservative and wouldn't it reduce the power of your study or am I thinking strictly of the Bonferroni correction?

Comment: You're thinking strictly of Bonferroni. Holm-Bonferroni is uniformly more powerful. Although potentially better alternatives to Holm-Bonferroni exist, such as the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure, so I've updated my answer to remove this unnecessary specificity.